# Discord.js - Set a channel description

Tags: discord, discord.js, channel

I was trying to set a channels description, but I couldn't find it in the discord.js docs. Does any one know the code for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are looking for: [`channel.setTopic()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setTopic).
Example:

```
// Set a new channel topic
channel.setTopic('Needs more rate limiting')
  .then(updated => console.log(`Channel's new topic is ${updated.topic}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .setTopic() function. For example:

```
<channel>.setTopic('Topic here')
```